# Вітати, привітати, поздоровляти (вітаю, привітаю, поздоровляю)

Tags: значення-слів, різниця-між-словами, вживання-слів

Чи правильно казати українською `вітати з днем народження`? Або все ж більш правильно використовувати інше слово?

`Вітати` здається мені інтуїтивно більш розповсюдженим і "літературним". `Поздоровляти`, з іншого боку, здається калькою з російської або якимось місцевим діалектизмом, хоча я не можу це нічим довести. Більш того, словники, зазвичай, наводять всі ці слова як правильні переклади, тому це зовсім не допомагає мені обрати якесь з них для вживання. Коли я, наприклад, уявляю собі диктора на телебаченні або радіо, то мені важко уявити собі, як він/вона каже: "Поздоровляємо Наталку з днем народження!"

Comment: "поздоровляти" необов'язково може бути калькою з російської, адже деякі інші слов'янські мови також мають це слово: `powitać`/`pozdrawiać` (польська), `pozdravljat` (хорватська).

Comment: «Поздоровляти» цілком може бути калькою з російської. Але це нормативна калька, підтверджена словниками та мовною практикою.

Answer (score 13):

Дієлова "вітати" та "поздоровляти" є синонімами:

[**ВІТАТИ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/vitaty)

> 2. *перех., кого з чим.* Висловлювати комусь почуття радості, задоволення з приводу якоїсь події, успіху та ін.; **поздоровляти**. *Товариші весело вітали її з успіхом (Олесь Донченко, VI, 1957, 163)*;

[**ПОЗДОРОВЛЯТИ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/pozdorovljaty)

> 1. **Вітати** когось з нагоди якої-небудь радісної, приємної події (народження, одруження, ювілею і т. ін.). *Досадно мені, що я не встиг поздоровити Юрка в день його родин (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 407);*

Також є менш вживані форми:

[ВІНШУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vinshuvaty)

> *недок., перех. і неперех., рідко.* Те саме, що **поздоровляти**; вітати. *Віншують гості, подарунки виймають, розв'язавши клунки: «Твоїм добром — тобі ж чолом!» (Леся Українка, I, 1951, 280);*

[ҐРАТУЛЮВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/gratuljuvaty) (див. також [тут](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=4544&hilit=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8))

> *недок., кому, діал.* **Вітати**, **поздоровляти**. *— А! Ґратулюю вам! — промовив Дарко.. радісним голосом (Осип Маковей, Вибр., 1954, 45);*

Але якщо взяти до уваги тлумачення відповідних іменників "вітання" та "поздоровлення", то можна помітити, що перший з них має більш загальне значення, а другий дійсно можна використовувати для опису самого процесу:

[**ВІТАННЯ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/vitannja)

> 1. Слова або жести, звернені до кого-небудь під час зустрічі на знак прихильного ставлення, доброзичливості і т. ін. //  Вияв приязні, прихильного ставлення до когось.
> 2. Усне або письмове поздоровлення чи побажання здоров'я, успіхів і т. ін.
> 3. рідко. Пригощання, частування когось чим-небудь.

[**ПОЗДОРОВЛЕННЯ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/pozdorovlennja)

> 1. Дія за значенням поздоровити, поздоровляти.
> 2. Привітання з нагоди якої-небудь радісної, приємної події (народження, одруження, ювілею і т. ін.).

У якості прикладу офіційного вживання можна подивитись [відповідний розділ](http://www.president.gov.ua/news/greetings) на сайті Президента України.

Answer (score 9):

Суто власне ІМХО, не підкріплюване нічим, крім власних спостережень за літературною мовою. "Вітати <з якоїсь нагоди>" - більш вживана норма, як-от "вітання з д.н.", "новорічне привітання президента" тощо.

"Поздоровляти" - радше дієслово для описання процесу. "Наталко, вітаємо з днем народження" / "Що робиш?" - "Та от, поздоровляємо Наталку".

Comment: Чисто інтуїтивно мені Ваша думка видається вірною. Від «поздоровляю» не для опису процесу, а в самій вітальній фразі («поздоровляю Вас з …!») мені особисто віє росіянізмом (під впливом російського «поздравляю Вас с …!», яке там є майже єдиним можливим варіантом).

Comment: Але з іншого боку «поздоровляю» саме в цьому значенні (в складі самої вітальної фрази) вживають Г. Квітка-Основ'яненко («Маруся», 1834), П. Куліш («Чорна рада», 1857), І. Нечуй-Левицький (багаторазово з 1869 до 1903), П. Мирний («Повія», 1883), В. Винниченко («Божки», 1919), ну й, звісно, радянські та сучасні письменники.

Comment: Тож одне з двох: або ми з Вами помиляємося (що цілком імовірно), або сучасна літературна норма трішки змінилася в напрямку відмежування від російської традиції (що насправді навряд).